# "Sharing" enchanted items in Dresden Files RPG

Tags: dresden-files, fate, magic-items

One of my players brought up the example of the Warden's Sword as an enchanted item. For those not so familiar with the source books, these are powerful enchanted swords made by Captain Luccio, the leader of the Wardens, personalized to the warden they're to be assigned to, and then given to them. They're even given as example enchanted items in the book. Mechanically speaking, though, any enchanted item you make counts against your enchanted item limit. After a bit of conversation, we came up with two main options:

1. Enchanted item slots mainly cover maintaining enchanted items and the thaumaturgy casting is what lets one perform it, so the sword counts against the recipient's enchanted item slots.
2. Potions count for enchanted item slots, and they don't need maintenance and can be freely given away, so the sword counts against the maker's enchanted item slots.

Is there a third option we haven't found here? If not, which of these is most suitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that it depends on the circumstances like with almost everything FATE.  Grabbing the unconscious warden's sword & using it to defend him against the warlock he was fighting will probably work great.  Using it still six months after you defeated the warlock & slit the warden's throat... not so much as more than just a sword though.  Something like Harry's highly personal shield bracelet, no because there are rules for added cost/reduced power on share-able stuff like that.  his armored coat might work fine for someone else in an emergency because it's not something you actively use beyond simply wearing it & hoping it works for a scene or two .  An enchanted gun to be more accurate/deadly or something you have to actively use might not be any more effective than a regular gun unless it's like the colt in supernatural where it has x many bullets & they can never be replaced since the person that spent the refresh to be able to make them is long dead. If the magic s in the gun itself though, the magic could very well be attuned to the owner or particular goal & not work right for anyone/anything else if the usage is more  than something like finishing up the fight where the owner was taken out.

Remember, you have a lot more bodies to shift cost of items off of those using them, if your players are abusing things, remind them that if what they are doing is really fine & danfy then NPCs would probably be doing the same kind of thing & you can use enchanted items paid for by who knows without complaint.

Comment: Harry's shield bracelet is a focus, not an enchanted item. The kinetic rings are examples of enchanted items.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your players are 'borrowing' the enchanted items of PCs, one player will be losing one of their advantages to another player without gaining anything. This remains fairly balanced. On the other hand, if they're "Greyhawking the bodies" you should probably account for this when outfitting the enemies. If an item is too powerful (or belonged to someone using 'dark magic') there's a decent chance the White Council will swoop in to confiscate it. Also, enchanted items don't last forever (per Dresden needing to re-up his jacket), so unless they pay the upkeep (refresh rate), have it run out at the end of the story. Or better yet, have it give out at critical moment.

Comment: I assume "Greyhawking" here is yet another euphenism for "picking up anything on the body that isn't nailed down"?

Comment: @Ashen Yes. The golden standard of such things, even, being that Castle Greyhawk was Gary Gygax's original campaign setting (whereby experience was gained through means of looting).

Answer (score 1):

`YS92` has notes for Temporary Powers in the sidebar.  I'd say that if the maker of the item gives it, then he can lend the use of his enchanted item slots.  But if the maker does not/is not available, then the Temporary Powers rules should be used.  Stat the item's effects up as an Item of Power (`YS167`), and the person that wants to use it has to pay the Fate points for the temporary power(s), with the attendant problems if they go negative in the Fate point area.

Story wise, it can be represented in a few different ways.  One example off the top of my head: the PC picks up the enchanted sword, and doesn't have the Fate points to pay the cost.  The sword starts to speak to him- does he drop it, or are the circumstances dire enough to pay the cost?